# Stuck Building for iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, targets

I recently took my plain-vanilla C++ project in XCode, and added a new iPhone target. Now, however, I can't build my old C++ target for the Mac anymore; it's stuck on "iPhone Simulator." When I compile, it gives me the error `target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform`, which makes perfect sense-- I just don't want to compile for the iPhone at all.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the XCode 4 beta, and it worked fine, so it seems just to be a bug in XCode 3.